# Can you take pictures in the Wii U of YOURSELF like in the 3DS, not just Mii's Face

Tags: wii-u

I got a Wii U, and it's awesome. I like the features. There is only one thing that disappoints me; that I can't find how to take pictures of myself or other people with the camera. It seems that I can't take pictures of myself and other people like in the 3DS. I can only take pictures of my face for the Mii. On the 3DS you can take and save them, but I don't know if you can on the Wii U. If you can then I don't know how to. Can you take pictures on the Wii U for other reasons than the Mii?

Comment: I've found almost zero use for the camera after having owned a Wii U since this past summer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a couple of threads on other forums asking similar questions, it looks like this is not possible - [**only the ability to take screenshots in game**](https://www.nintendo.com/wiiu/image-share/).

[NintendoLife - Does the wii u have the capabilities to take pictures/photoshop?](http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/wii-u/does_the_wii_u_have_the_capabilities_to_take_picturesphotoshop)

[GameFAQs - How to take pictures?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/631516-wii-u/64710056)

[IGN - Can the Wii U's camera actually take photos? And if so, how?](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/can-the-wii-us-camera-actually-take-photos-and-if-so-how.452760700/)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to save them, but it is for certain games that support it (like M&S @ Sochi and Wii Fit U). But beyond that? No. Because the Wii U is a home console, and not a handheld, it would have no use no matter what.